Powerapp Canvas app - How to get email addresses of a Sharepoint List Person column?
I have a Sharepoint list that has the columns:

Step (integer starts from 1)

Document (lookup column from a Sharepoint Library)

Type of Task (a Choice column containing Draft, Review)

Users (Person/Group Column that Allow Multiple Selections).
Example of the list:
 Step   Document   Type of Task   Users
 1      Doc1       Draft          Smith,John Smith, Mary
 2      Doc1       Review         Smith, Anne



In my Powerapp canvas app, how can I get the emails of Document Doc1, Step 1 ie. emails of Smith,John and Smith, Mary, so that I can send an email to this list of people ?
Thank you

I'm not sure how you want to implement this exactly, but the key thing you'll want is something like: A gallery with your SharePoint list as your data source and some way to use this formula: Concat(ThisItem.Users,Email,";")

Assuming you are using integrated Power Apps form (not custom Canvas App), you need to:

Find combo-box control inside "Users" field card
"Unlock it" in Advanced properties tab
Change property DisplayFields value to ["Email"]


In case you are using non-integrated Canvas app:

Find column control inside your table (that has a source of SP list)

Update Text property to Concat(ThisItem.'[--field--]', Email, ", ")



Hello,
Thank you for your reply. We are displaying the Sharepoint list in a Table in Canvas App. Is there a DisplayFields property in a table ? If I need to do the same thing from a PowerAutomate, how can I do that ? Thank you

Answer updated. :)

Thank you for your help.
